# How to form a linear model when not all variable types were measured at the same samples / when different variables have different replication?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, variability

I am wondering how to incorporate different measurements, that were not taken from the same sample/individual and that have a different number of replication, into one model.

As for now it is a rather theoretical question, unfortunately I don't have any data to come with it. But I am going to try to describe a possible scenario:

Let's assume there are measurements from 100 locations.
At each location, meteorological variables are measured (mean annual temperature or annual precipitation therefore have **one value per location**). Biological factors such as species number or biomass would be measured on 10 random subsamples per location, yielding **10 replicates per location**. Other physical measurements may be less readily available or may be less fluctuating, such as soil pH or profile depth. Thus they are measured at 6 random locations, resulting in **6 replicates per location**.

All these variables are continuous and cannot simply be attributed to the location, i.e. in form of a grouped factor.

What I was wondering is, whether there is any other way to analyse such a dataset beside taking the mean of each variable for a location? Such a reduced dataset with only means would reduce the natural variability considerably. My guess would be that such "patchy" datasets exist quite often, but so far I haven't come across any common way to analyse such data.
Are there models where e.g. the mean and sd could be considered?